# Can't login with different user in sencha cordova app

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, sencha-touch

I am using facebook connect plugin in my cordova app.With first user it is working well but when I am trying to logout from my app and facebook and try with another facebook account it is again logging in with the first account which I have tried first time and credentials are there why not destroyed.

https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin

please help!